# How to update tables from an external Access database with identical tables?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Using MS Access, via VBA, I have been trying to update an main Access database table from an identically structured external Access database table.  Same columns, same fields.  The external databases are used to update a central main database.

What I have been trying to develop is a line of SQL that only appends the entries that are completely unique.  Because there is no foreign keys or unique identifiers for the incoming data that can be referenced, I am required to check each field to make sure that there are no exact duplicates.  So, if the table had 2 fields, if entries failed the logic test
 `intTable.field1 = extTable.field1 And intTable.field2 = extTable.field2`
then those are the entries that would be appended.

The code I came up with is below, and when it runs it tries to append (in a Gary Oldman voice) EVERYTHING.  I can't find out what could be wrong with it, as it's almost like it ignores the `WHERE` or `WHERE NOT EXIST`.  I have tried dozens of small edits and alternate versions.  Either is appends all or none.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
FROM [;DATABASE=C:\extDB.accdb].[Table1] sourceDB 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM [;DATABASE=C:\extDB.accdb].[Table1] sourceDB1 
                  WHERE ('Table1.[field1]'='sourceDB1.[field1]' And 
                         'Table1.[field2]'='sourceDB1.[field2]' And 
                         'Table1.[field3]'='sourceDB1.[field3]' And 
                         'Table1.[field4]'='sourceDB1.[field4]' And 
                         'Table1.[field5]'='sourceDB1.[field5]'));
```

---

FINAL CODE (after implementing ArcherBird's solution):

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5
FROM [;DATABASE=C:\extDB.accdb].[Table1] sourceDB 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM [;DATABASE=C:\extDB.accdb].[Table1] sourceDB1 
                  WHERE ((sourceDB.[field1] = sourceDB1.[field1] Or (sourceDB.[field1] IS NULL And sourceDB1.[field1] IS NULL)) And 
                         (sourceDB.[field2] = sourceDB1.[field2] Or (sourceDB.[field2] IS NULL And sourceDB1.[field2] IS NULL)) And 
                         (sourceDB.[field3] = sourceDB1.[field3] Or (sourceDB.[field3] IS NULL And sourceDB1.[field3] IS NULL)) And 
                         (sourceDB.[field4] = sourceDB1.[field4] Or (sourceDB.[field4] IS NULL And sourceDB1.[field4] IS NULL)) And 
                         (sourceDB.[field5] = sourceDB1.[field5] Or (sourceDB.[field5] IS NULL And sourceDB1.[field5] IS NULL)) ));
```

Comment: That not exists will never return true because those quotes are not field delimiters in Access, but string delimiters. Just remove all quotes from that query and it'll probably run just fine.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth When I remove the quotes, Access prompts me to enter parameter values.  I initially had that issue, and a solution elswhere stated the single-quote marks as a fix since the fields' data types are text.

Comment: I think your `Table1` references in the `WHERE` clause should be `sourceDB` as this is your alias in the `FROM` clause. This combined with removing the quotes ought to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Remove the string quotes from your field comparison logic.

2) You have aliased `Table1` in your query as `sourceDB`, so use that reference.

3) The table where you check for non-existence ought to be the "local" version of `Table1` (the one you are inserting into).

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
SELECT field1, 
       field2, 
       field3, 
       field4, 
       field5
FROM [;DATABASE=C:\extDB.accdb].[Table1] sourceDB
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                  FROM [Table1] sourceDB1 
                  WHERE (sourceDB.[field1] = sourceDB1.[field1] And 
                         sourceDB.[field2] = sourceDB1.[field2] And 
                         sourceDB.[field3] = sourceDB1.[field3] And 
                         sourceDB.[field4] = sourceDB1.[field4] And 
                         sourceDB.[field5] = sourceDB1.[field5]));
```

EDIT:

To deal with the case where these fields might have `null` values, you cannot do a simple `=` comparison since `null` does not equal `null`. The best way I can think of to get around this in MS Access would be to replace `null` with some other value that is not likely to be used. In doing so, you also need to make sure you chose replacement values that are consistent with the data type. I will make an assumption that all your fields are text.

```
INSERT INTO Table1 
    SELECT field1, 
           field2, 
           field3, 
           field4, 
           field5
    FROM [;DATABASE=C:\extDB.accdb].[Table1] sourceDB
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * 
                      FROM [Table1] sourceDB1 
                      WHERE (nz(sourceDB.[field1],"!@#") = nz(sourceDB1.[field1],"!@#") And 
                             nz(sourceDB.[field2],"!@#") = nz(sourceDB1.[field2],"!@#") And 
                             nz(sourceDB.[field3],"!@#") = nz(sourceDB1.[field3],"!@#") And 
                             nz(sourceDB.[field4],"!@#") = nz(sourceDB1.[field4],"!@#") And 
                             nz(sourceDB.[field5],"!@#") = nz(sourceDB1.[field5],"!@#")));
```

Comment: Okay, part way there.  Now, in my test DB, it is appending 304 out of 1579 records.  I there should only be 4.  The rest of the external DB is an exact duplicate (copy and paste) of the current DB, but I added 4 unique test entries.  For some reason it is reading exactly 300 of them as unique.

Comment: Even if I run the query multiple times, it still keeps pulling those 300 entries.  I mean, although they might not have been seen as duplicates before the run (even though they were) they certainly should be after it Inserted the exact entry.

Comment: @LazyBear I'm willing to bet that those 300 records have `null` values in one of those comparison fields. `Null = Null` would always return `false`; which means the `NOT EXISTS` would never see that as a duplicate value. You would need to do some sort of null replacement/checking to deal with those cases. I'll update my answer with a suggestions to deal with that case

Comment: That's it! Thank you. I used the following to sort it out: `(sourceDB.[field1] = sourceDB1.[field1] Or (sourceDB.[field1] IS NULL And sourceDB1.[field1] IS NULL))`  I didn't see your code until now, just the comment.  But both seem to work.

Comment: Nice, I like your solution better - the IsNull checks. Glad to have helped @LazyBear